# simple MongoDB MR not producing expected result

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I know it may be crazy easy or whatever but last few hours I am banging my head around this. I am lost. I have a collection which looks like this (each document structure is the same)

```
{
   "_id": "736722976",
   "value": {
     "tag_cloud": {
       "0": {
         "0": "FIFA World Cup 2014",
         "1": " Germany",
         "2": " Algeria",
         "3": " Thomas Muller",
         "4": " Mesut Ozil"
      },
       "1": {
         "0": "Monsoon",
         "1": " Germany"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I am trying to run a map-reduce on this to produce the total number of each tags appearing in the cloud.This is how my mr code looks like

```
var map = function(){
  emit(this._id, this.value.tag_cloud);
}

var reduce = function(key, values){
    var mm = new Array();
    values.forEach(function(v){
        for (i in v){
            k = v[i].trim();
            if (k in mm){
                mm[k] = mm[k] + 1;
            }else{
                mm[k] = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    return {tag: mm};
}

db.analysis_mid.mapReduce(map, reduce, 
        {
            out: "analysis_result"
        }
);
```

and I am running this like ---

```
mongo localhost:27017/my_db_name_with_mother_collection mr.js
```

And it runs pretty fine. No errors whatsoever. But then, the result it produces looks like this---

```
{
   "_id": "736722976",
   "value": {
     "0": {
       "0": "FIFA World Cup 2014",
       "1": " Germany",
       "2": " Algeria",
       "3": " Thomas Muller",
       "4": " Mesut Ozil"
    },
     "1": {
       "0": "Monsoon",
       "1": " Germany"
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea how is this possible. What am I missing here? Can somebody please help me?

The desired output should be ---

```
{ 
    "_id": "736722976",
    "tag": {
        "FIFA World Cup 2014": 1,
        "Germany": 2,
        "Algeria": 1,
        "Thomas Muller": 1,
        "Mesut Ozil": 1,
        "Monsoon": 1
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see different errors, first, `mm` is an object, not an array (you need a string key), second, you can't apply `forEach()` in a object (the value emitted in the map), you have to do a for loop.

It seems if you have a error in the code (the forEach()``), the reduce is not executed.

Comment: hey! You are right actually. I figured it out before sometime. I have made some changes in the code and it is working well now. Thanks anyway :)